# Why is the relative Lie algebra of a $p$-twisted elliptic curve over a $\mathbb{F}_p$-scheme isomorphic to the $p$th-tensor power of the Lie algebra?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $S$ be an $\mathbb{F}_p$-scheme, and $E/S$ an elliptic curve. Pulling back $E/S$ by the absolute frobenius $F_{abs} : S\rightarrow S$ yields a $p$-twisted elliptic curve $E^{(p)}$.

In Katz-Mazur's book, $\S$12.4 (p353), they give a slick description of the Hasse invariant as a modular form of weight $p-1$. However, here, they seem to use the isomorphism:

$$Lie(E/S)^{(p)}\cong Lie(E/S)^{\otimes p}$$

(This is an isomorphism of invertible sheaves on *the base* $S$).

Why is this true?

The only thing I can imagine is that maybe the absolute frobenius acts by multiplication by $p$ on picard groups, but I don't think that's true (consider an elliptic curve over $\mathbb{F}_p$).

Comment: The lie algebra is just the tangent space at the identity. If the isomorphism you speak of is true, you should be able to compute with the cotangent space $\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2$ at the identity (maybe with coordinates after choosing an embedding to $\Bbb P^2$?) and then use the duality between cotangent and tangent spaces to conclude what you want. I'm rusty on the details (in particular, I'm rusty enough that I can't tell you immediately whether what you want is true or not!) but this would seem to be the place to start.

Comment: @KReiser There is a subtlety here (which I've made a bit clearer in my post). This is the *relative Lie algebra*, viewed as an invertible sheaf on $S$. Thus, it's nontriviality has to do with the geometry of the family $E/S$. (Of course if $S$ is a field, the Lie algebra of any elliptic curve over a field is just a 1-dimensional vector space, and so is certainly isomorphic to its $p$th tensor power)